# How to get specific data out of upcdatabase.org API (Python)

Tags: python

Using the requests package, I'm trying to access the upcdatabase.org API, just to get a certain part of the returned data to be printed off. The data returned looks like this:

```
{
    "upc": "5705831011120",
    "name": "Pink highlighter",
    "alias": "Highlighter",
    "description": "It's a pink highlighter. Here's some more information as 
well.",
    "brand": "Q-CONNECT",
    "msrp": 0.99,
    "status": 200,
    "error": false
}
```

I'm trying to just get the name to print out, but it appears to be returned to python as a string, not as a list.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: That looks like JSON data. Do you know how to work with JSON? Why are you expecting a list? Are you expecting a list of many results, or a single result? What is the exact request that you're making? Please read [ask].

Comment: `raw = api_stuff(); data = json.loads(raw); print(data['name'])`